# Use just one class instead of two

Tags: css

I have the following class which I use in multiple places like labels etc

```
.cont-label.ope-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: ariel;
    font-size: 18px;

}
```

now for header I want to add just 
color for specific class ,there is a way **not to do it like that** ?

```
.cont-label.ope-label-new {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: ariel;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:red;

}
```

Comment: Would be nice to know what your Header Element is.

Comment: Just curious, is "ariel" an actual font? :)

Comment: if it is just a color then you can combine classes for rest of the css and write specific css for color... like .cont-label.ope-label-new, .cont-label.ope-label-new {common css} and .cont-label.ope-label-new {color:red;}

Comment: Can't u use another class for Header and add only color property for that. Then you can use additional class for headers only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just give the header a class of the colour you want and overwrite that:

```
<h1 class="cont-label ope-label red">test</h1>
```

then css:

```
.red {color:red;}
```

if your original header has a colour set then specificity will come into it:

```
.cont-label.ope-label.red {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `<header>` element, use just

```
header .cont-label.ope-label {color: red;}
```

If `header` should be only class/id, use the similar

```
.header .cont-label.ope-label {color: red;}
/* or for ID */
#header .cont-label.ope-label {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**HTML:**

```
<header> 
<div class="cont-label ope-label">
... 
</div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cont-label.ope-label,header.cont-label.ope-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18px;    
}

.cont-label.ope-label {
    color:blue;    
}

header.cont-label.ope-label {   
    color:red;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an css hierarchy like

```
.header .cont-label.ope-label{
      color: red;
    }
```